# Xfburn: fehlgeschlagen, Burn Run failed

Tags: cd, burning, cd-drive

Ich benutze Xubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, momentan mit dem Linuxkern 4.4.0-145-generic x86_64
Außerdem xfburn version 0.5.4 for Xfce 4.12

Ich verwende einen Lenovo W530, der enthält ein CD/DVD-RW-Laufwerk MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8C0. Xfburn zeigt dafür alle Haken, außer bei "blue ray schreiben".

Die zu verwendenden Datenträger sind Verbatim CD-R 700 MB 52x.

Der FIFO-Puffer von Xfburn ist auf dem maximal einstellbaren Wert,bei mir also auf 16384 kB.

Ich bekomme trotzdem immer wieder Fehlermeldungen der Art

> Fehlgeschlagen: Burn Run failed.

Beim FIFO-Puffer zeigt das Meldungsfenster 99%, beim Gerätepuffer 100%.

Bei den Einstellungen waren dabei Haken gesetzt bei:
CD auswerfen,
Simulieren,
Burn Free,
Datenstromaufnahme.

Bei "nur ISO erzeugen" war kein Haken gesetzt.
(Ich habe auch schon versucht, die CD mit der kleinst möglichen Geschwindigkeit zu brennen, aber das half auch nicht).

**Was ist da falsch?**

Comment: Please post in English. Thanks!

Comment: I have done so at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131646/xfburn-fails-burn-run-failed.